# Why Remix JavaScript VM and Web3 Provider show different behavior at the time CALL is made?

Tags: remix, gas, evm

I'm using Geth evm version 1.8.4-stable to run private network and I see different behavior on `CALL` between the Remix environment of Javascript VM and Web3 Provider.

On this example, using `callHi()` makes difference. It works fine with JavaScript VM, but Web3 Provider fails. Web3 Provider needs gas specification to avoid this failure.

According to [0.4.21 release](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/commit/83fcf007bfdf9c9c8b595369c0542d45943ee095?diff=split), `CALL` does not automatically send the remaining gas. Therefore we need to specify the gas amount when using `CALL` otherwise it fails to run after 0.4.21.

I understand gas specification is needed to avoid reentrancy issue, but why JavaScript VM still allows `CALL` without gas specification? Is it a bug or evm version difference?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract Hi {
    event SayHi(string);
    function hi() public { emit SayHi("Hi!");}
    function callHi() public {
        // OK with JavaScript VM, 
        // OK with Web3 Provider, compiled with ^0.4.20
        // Not OK with Web3 Provider, compiled with ^0.4.21 and later
        require(address(this).call(bytes4(keccak256("hi()"))));  

        // Web3 Provider needs gas specification to fix Error
        // require(address(this).call.gas(2000)(bytes4(keccak256("hi()"))));
    }
}
```